# checking range of number and writing a value in a new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to iterate over column 'movies_rated', check the value against the conditions, and write a value in a newly create column 'expert_level'. When I test on a subset of data, it works. But when I run it against my whole dateset, it only gets filled with value 1.

```
for num in df_merge['movies_rated']:
    if num in range(20,31):
        df_merge['expert_level'] = 1
    elif num in range(31,53):
        df_merge['expert_level'] = 2
    elif num in range(53,99):
        df_merge['expert_level'] = 3
    elif num in range(99,202):
        df_merge['expert_level'] = 4
    else:
        df_merge['expert_level'] = 5
```

here's a sample dataframe.

```
movies = [88,20,35,55,1203,99,2222,847]
name = ['angie','chris','pine','benedict','alice','spock','tony','xena']
df = pd.DataFrame(movies,name,columns=['movies_rated'])
```

certainly there's a less verbose way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with the `pandas` function [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) is a good choice for you:

```
conds = [df.movies_rated.between(20,30), df.movies_rated.between(31,52),
         df.movies_rated.between(53,98), df.movies_rated.between(99,202)]


choices = [1,2,3,4]


df['expert_level'] = np.select(conds,choices, 5)

>>> df
          movies_rated  expert_level
angie               88             3
chris               20             1
pine                35             2
benedict            55             3
alice             1203             5
spock               99             4
tony              2222             5
xena               847             5
```

Comment: This doesn't quite give the same results because of boundary handling (look at Spock: 99 should be 4, not 3.)

Comment: Good point! I've edited that. It was because `between` is by default inclusive, so you need to set the conditions appropriately (you can also set `inclusive=False`, but in any case, you need to pay attention to your conditions)

Comment: I have been using this in my project, but was stumped with checking for range. Thanks for highlighting 'between' to me.

Answer (score 3):

You could build an `IntervalIndex` and then apply `pd.cut`.  I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find one right now which uses both `closed='left'` and `.codes`, though I'm sure it exists.

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([0, 20, 31, 53, 99, 202, np.inf], closed='left')
df["expert_level"] = pd.cut(movies, bins).codes
```

which gives me

```
In [242]: bins
Out[242]: 
IntervalIndex([[0.0, 20.0), [20.0, 31.0), [31.0, 53.0), [53.0, 99.0), [99.0, 202.0), [202.0, inf)]
              closed='left',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

and

```
In [243]: df
Out[243]: 
          movies_rated  expert_level
angie               88             3
chris               20             1
pine                35             2
benedict            55             3
alice             1203             5
spock               99             4
tony              2222             5
xena               847             5
```

Note that I've set this up so that scores below 20 get a 0 value, so they can be distinguished from really high rankings.  If you really want everything outside the bins to get 5, it'd be straightforward to remap 0 to 5, or just pass breaks of [20, 31, 53, 99, 202] and then map anything with a code of -1 (which means 'not binned') to 5.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with `apply` and a function:

```
def  expert_level_check(num):
    if 20<= num < 31:
        return 1
    elif 31<= num < 53:
        return 2
    elif 53<= num < 99:
        return 3
    elif 99<= num < 202:
        return 4
    else:
        return 5

df['expert_level'] = df['movies_rated'].apply(expert_level_check)
```

it is slower to manually iterate over a df, I recommend reading [this](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: oh, sorry about that. still faster than manualy iterating through :) . let me edit my answer.

Comment: appreciate the reading material. As a newbie, I begin to see how important speed starts to become when dealing with larger datasets. Guess there are plenty of ways to 'skin a cat'. cheers!